# jQuery inefficiency?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, session, database-connection

I'm still learning jQuery and I haven't figured out some of the concepts yet, so I'm sorry if this is a very noob question, but I have a problem when retrieving information with jQuery from PHP/MySQL in the following manner:

```
$.get('backend.php', {}, function (data) {
    doSomething(data);
});
```

I don't know if I'm doing something wrong, but even if I create the connection and the session with a `<?php ?>` tag in the `index.php`, when jQuery calls to the `backend.php` file, it behaves like if they were never created.

Do I have to renew the database connection and call `session_start` every single time I ask for the new data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You do. On the server every page-call is a new page-call to the server.** That's the reason you use cookies/tokens/whatever to follow users across a site.

On the bright side that is exactly the same reason why you can have a farm full of "dumb" servers that will round-robin your users and everything will still "hold". I would strongly recomend you do some work on PHP/Apache (server) and only then switch to jQuery/Ajax (client) as you will get a stronger grasp of what's server-side and what's client-side.

Answer (score 1):

You do need to do all that, but to make things easier, you can create a global file (e.g. `init.php`) that could be included in all your scripts so you don't have to write the same thing over and over.